# Database locked (or slow) with Linq To Entities and Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities

I'm using Linq To Entities (L2E) ONLY to map all my Stored Procedures in my database for easy translation into objects. My data is not really sensitive (so I'm considering Isolation level "READ UNCOMMITED" everywhere). I have several tables with millions of rows. I have the website and a bunch of scripts utilizing the same datamodel created using entity framework. I have indexed all tables (max 3 for each table) so that every filter I use is directly catched by an index. My scripts mainly consists of

1) Get your from DB (~5 seconds)
2) Making API (1-3 seconds)
3) Adding result in database

I have READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION set to ON.

Using this strategy most my queries is fixed and very fast (usually). I still have some queries used by my scripts that could run up to 20 second but the are not called that often.

The problem is that suddenly the whole database gets slow and all my queries are returned slowly (can be over 10 seconds). Using Sql Profiler I have tried to find the issue.

As mentioned Im considering NOLOCKS using "READ UNCOMMITED"... Right now I'm going through each possible database call and adding indexes and/or caching tables to make the call faster.

I have also considered removing L2E and accesing the "old way" to be sure thats not the issue. Is My data context looking my tables? it sure looks that way. I have experimenting haveing the context living over the API call to minimize created context but right now I create a new context for each call since I thought it was looking the database.

The problem is that I cannot control, that every single call is made fast, for all eternity otherwise the whole system gets slowed down.

When I restart sql server and rebuild indexes its really fast for a short period of time before everything gets slow again. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered checking if there are any major waits on the server.

Review the following page on [sys.dm_os_wait_stats (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx) and see if you can get any insight into why the server is slow....

Comment: Actually, I turned off everything not essential 2 weeks ago and I re-index every night now and the problem is gone. I will try to reactivate the scripts one by one and see if I get the problem back, then I will check your tip. Thanks.